# Loop issue from Elegant javascript Chapter 2 Exercise 3

Tags: javascript

This question comes from the above source, in which I'm asked to make a chess board. The provided solution uses the same method, except y < size and x < size. But why doesn't this way work?

---

```
var size = 8;
var chess = "";

for (var y = 0; y == size; y++){
    for (var x = 0; x == size; x++){

        if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)
            chess += " ";
        else
            chess += "#";

    }
    chess += "\n";    
}

console.log(chess);
```

--

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand how the `for` loop works. Read up on it at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for.

The second clause is a **condition** which is checked each time through the loop, including at the very beginning. If it is *false*, then the loop is exited. The loop continues while it is *true*. In your case, you want to keep looping until `x` or `y` has reached the size of the board (actually, the size of the board less 1, since we are starting at 0). Therefore, the following **is** correct:

```
for (var y = 0; y < size; y++) {
                ^^^^^^^^
```

If you do what you did, and say

```
for (var y = 0; y == size; y++){
                ^^^^^^^^^
```

then the loop will **never execute at all**. It will start off with an `x` of zero, then check if that is equal to `size` which it is not (`0 !== 8`), and therefore exit the loop without even executing it once.

Answer (score 1):

Since `x` and `y` value change, the conditions for `for loops` should be `<`.

This should work:

```
var size = 8;
var chess = "";

for (var y = 0; y < size; y++){

    for (var x = 0; x < size; x++){

        if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)
            chess += " ";
        else
            chess += "#";
    }

    chess += "\n";    
}

console.log(chess);
```